# Django tutorial maximum depth recursion

Tags: python, django, recursion

I am doing the django first app tutorial. When I try access the localhost webpage, I get a maximum depth recursion error. The check method keeps on getting returned until maximum depth. The code is as follows for urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url
from polls import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name ='index'),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

View.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello World. You're at the polls index")
```

The error code:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
return check_method()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 255, in check
warnings.extend(check_resolver(pattern))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
return check_method()
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

What can I do to remedy this?
Thank you

Comment: please include urls.py from polls module. Whichever view you are accessing please include that view with full error traceback.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you are including the polls urls inside itself.

Remove `url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),` from your `polls/urls.py`.

That line should be in your project's urls.py instead (by default, that's the one in the directory that contains `settings.py`)

You should move `url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),` to your project's `urls.py` as well.

Comment: In my case, I was trying to import a module that had the same name as my project and main app, leading to a conflict in urls. I could have changed the url path or renamed the project (I chose the latter to be safe).